# ng-select with async options and default value

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have an `ng-select` dropdown with async options fetched from an API.
The API is paginated using Spring Boot's `Pageable` and supports searching using RSQL.
So the dropdown shows the first 50 items, and if you start typing, it sends that search string to the API.

The problem comes when I want to have a default value in the dropdown, and that value is not in the first page returned by the API.
So the dropdown looks like it is empty to the user, even though it does actually have a default value.

```
<ng-select
    [items]="connections$ | async"
    bindLabel="name"
    bindValue="id"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [typeahead]="typeahead"
    name="connection"
    class="form-control p-0"
>
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index" let-search="searchTerm">
        <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

```
export class Connection {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
}

...

let pageNum = 0;
let pageSize = 50;
this.typeahead = new Subject<string>();
this.connections$ = this.typeahead.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap((term) => {
        return this.connectionService.getConnections$(pageNum, pageSize, `name=="*${term}*"`).pipe(
            map((page) => page.content),
            catchError(() => of([])),
        );
    })
);

this.value = this.defaultConnectionId; // <------ This does not work when the defaultConnectionId is not on the first page
```

Is there a general approach to avoid this problem? It seems like it would apply to any UI framework that interacts with such an API.
Or is there a way in the API side to make sure the results include `this.defaultConnectionId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wanted a generic approach since I have many of these dropdowns, so this is what I ended up going for. It uses `withLatestFrom` to only check the `defaultValue` is part of the first page on the initial load, but not on subsequent searches.

```
public buildObservable<T extends { id?: number }>(
    typeahead: Subject<string>,
    pageObs: (pageable?: PageRequest, search?: string) => Observable<Page<T>>,
    idObs: (id: number) => Observable<T>,
    defVal?: number,
    filters?: string[],
  ): Observable<T[]>
  {
    const defValSub = new BehaviorSubject<number>(defVal);
    const page = new PageRequest(0, 50);
    const buildSearchStr = (term) => {
      const filtersCopy = filters ? [...filters] : [];
      if (term) {
        filtersCopy.push(`name=="*${term}*"`);
      }
      return filtersCopy.join(';');
    }

    return typeahead.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      withLatestFrom(defValSub),                            // start with default value
      filter(([term, defVal]) => term != null),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap(([term, defVal]) => pageObs(page, buildSearchStr(term)).pipe(
        catchError(() => of([])),                           // empty list on error
        tap(() => defValSub.next(null)),                    // reset the default value - just need it for the first load
        map((page: Page<T>) => page.content),
        mergeMap((arr: T[]) =>
          (!defVal || arr.find(item => item.id == defVal))  // if no defVal or it is part of the current page
          ? of(arr)                                         // then return the page itself
          : idObs(defVal).pipe(                             // otherwise get the item with defVal ID and add it to the page
              map(defValItem => {
                arr.push(defValItem);
                return arr;
              }),
              catchError(() => of(arr)),                    // on error return the page itself
            )
        )
      ))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- when you fetch the default Connection Id also fetch the connection name, then initialize the drop-down with a single value
- another alternative is to modify the api to accept an id, then then perform the search on the Id and populate the drop-down

One of these might help you solve the problem!

Comment: thank you. both of these approaches basically require to fetch the default value by ID separately (only if it does not appear in the first page), then add it to the options. I was just wondering if there is a cleaner or more general approach.

Comment: @andkov Initialize the dropdown with the default value hardcoded?